# Extracting data from a tuple in OCaml

Tags: tuples, ocaml

I'm trying to use the CIL library to parse C source code. I'm searching for a particular function using its name.

```
let cil_func = Caml.List.find (fun g ->
    match g with
    | GFun(f,_) when (equal f.svar.vname func) -> true
    | _ -> false
) cil_file.globals in
let body g = match g with GFun(f,_) -> f.sbody in
dumpBlock defaultCilPrinter stdout 1 (body cil_func)
```

So I have a type GFun of fundec * location, and I'm trying to get the sbody attribute of fundec.
It seems redundant to do a second pattern match, not to mention, the compiler complains that it's not exhaustive. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: You don't need a `match` expression to do pattern matching. You could just bind to the parts with a `let-in`.  `let body = (let GFun(f, _) = cil_func in f.sbody) in ...`

Comment: I still get an non-exhaustive pattern match warning with that approach.

Comment: I assume there are other constructors, so this would be non-exhaustive. If there are no other constructors, this is great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your own function that returns just the fundec:

```
let rec find_fundec fname = function
| [] -> raise Not_found
| GFun (f, _) :: _ when equal (f.svar.vname fname) -> f (* ? *)
| _ :: t -> find_fundec fname t
```

Then your code looks more like this:

```
let cil_fundec = find_fundec func cil_file.globals in
dumpBlock defaultCilPrinter stdout 1 cil_fundec.sbody
```

For what it's worth, the line marked `(* ? *)` looks wrong to me. I don't see why `f.svar.vname` would be a function. I'm just copying your code there.

**Update**

Fixed an error (one I often make), sorry.

Comment: I get the following error on the last pattern case:
Error: This expression has type Cil.global list -> Cil.fundec
       but an expression was expected of type Cil.fundec

Comment: I don't know Cil at all. But I believe my suggestion is workable if your original code is correct. Wait, I see what needs fixing.....

Comment: Ah I couldn't see that.. Must remember the "function" syntax implies the non-curried argument will be the one pattern matched.

Comment: Yes, this is my problem. I write the argument, then I decide to use `function`, then I forget to remove the argument.